# Регулярные выражения. Разрешить перенос строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.
Имеется выражение 
        `if (!preg_match('#[^A-zА-я0-9 _\-\=\+\(\)\*\!\?\.,]#ui',$_POST['edit']))`
но оно не допускает перенос строки(Enter)
Мне нужно чтобы перенос строки допускался.
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавь `\n`, а лучше `\r\n`.           .

Comment: if (!preg_match('#[^A-zА-я0-9 _\-\=\+\(\)\*\!\?\.,\r\n]#ui',$_POST['edit']))